# Unexpected HashSet.retain behavior

Tags: scala

I have this snippet of code where I am expecting a returned job with a given job_id to be removed from a mutable HashSet of running jobs using the retain function, however the expected entry is not being removed. I have some debug code below and its output (far below) that iterates through the set to show that there is an element in the set equal to the test element, but that the set size does not change when the retain function is used to only retain elements not equal to that job id.

```
if(action=="request_this") {
    println("RS >%d<\n".format(job.job_id))
    for(j <- jobs_running) println(">%d< ".format(j.job_id) + (if(j.job_id==job.job_id) "true" else "false"))
}

val c1 = jobs_running.size
jobs_running.retain(x => x.job_id!=job.job_id)
println(action+" NET CHANGE %d".format(jobs_running.size-c1))
```

Output:

```
RS >1259<

>1055< false
>1019< false
>1051< false
>1083< false
>1015< false
>1215< false
>1127< false
>1259< true
>1107< false
>1047< false
>1035< false
request_this NET CHANGE 0
```

What makes this even more puzzling to me is that the "action" var referenced in the debug code is just the plaintext equivalent to an action_id in the returning job object. It is only for for one job action type "request_this" that I can reproduce this problem. If it is a different type then I get the expected output ex:

```
request_that NET CHANGE -1
```

**UPDATE** -- The general consensus seems to be something related to hashcodes. I modified my debug code to print out the hashcodes for both the Job object and the job_id value.

```
if(action=="request_screenshot") {
    println(">>%d< ".format(job.job_id) + job.hashCode + " " + job.job_id.hashCode+"\n")
    for(j <- jobs_running) println(">%d< ".format(j.job_id) + j.hashCode + " " + j.job_id.hashCode)
}
```

The output I got back looks like the hashcodes of the test job (first line) and the jobs in the set match for both the job_id value and the overall job object (I put an * next to the matching set element printout):

```
>>1267< 1619488678 1267

>1015< 2124747326 1015
>1043< -183172091 1043
>1107< -353858330 1107
>1123< -1258875190 1123
>963< 1958632623 963
>1039< 226958301 1039
>1023< 148063445 1023
>1215< -972672885 1215
>959< 283572883 959
>971< -2080242470 971
>1091< -1549619606 1091
>1019< -529588663 1019
>1047< -552719093 1047
>967< 626939580 967
>1035< 1782547037 1035
>1263< -874427822 1263
>1027< -228877131 1027
>1031< 441847990 1031
*>1267< 1619488678 1267
>1211< -1435736028 1211
>1191< 48617136 1191
>1119< -1737229053 1119
>1011< 1056625401 1011
>1127< -1547902819 1127
>1251< -358437524 1251
```

**UPDATE2** -- I ended up rewriting my code so that the Job object was fully immutable and the symptom seems to have solved itself, though I still wish I understood what exactly was happening. Regarding the hashcode/equals implimentations being the culprit, it might be worth mentioning that the Job class was defined using "case class".

Comment: Broken implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` of set elements could cause stuff like this.

Comment: I was just going to ask: "set to show that there is an element in the set equal to the test element" equals as in "it looks like the other" or as in "obj1.equals(obj2)" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions:

1. Does the implementation of `hashCode` follow the [requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)? Perhaps you could provide their implementation.
2. Are the fields used by `hashCode` immutable, or, otherwise, not mutated after being inserted on the set?

**Edit**

Third question:

1. This is a `HashSet`, not a `SortedSet`, right? On a `SortedSet`, you need to worry about the `Ordering` implementation as well.

Comment: `equals` method too, isn't it?

Comment: @pedrofurla The output shown indicates `equals` returns true for some element, so even if it's not a good implementation, it ought to remove something.

Comment: The job_id value is immutable Int however other values in the overall Job object are mutable. The way I am thinking about it is that I believe Int datatypes are not refs, and the job_id is the only value being compared, so any hashCode should return a match. Is that correct, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @DanCollins Without looking at the `hashCode` code, I can't tell for sure, but here's the thing: if the value of `hashCode` changes between the time you put it on the set and the time you call `retain`, then the code will not be able to _find_ that element! It will be looking at a bucket based on the current `hashCode`, but it was stored in a bucket based on the original `hashCode`.